# is there a function to delete (in df1) the different rows in two df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

I have two DataFrame with different length. In **df1** i need to keep just the rows of df1 that are in df2 too and delete all the rows that are not in df1.
I used the function below that finds the difference between 2 df, but i won't be able to delete all the lines in df1.

```
df1[~(df1['F_Code'].isin(df2['Codice']))]
```

Comment: `df1[(df1['F_Code'].isin(df2['Codice']))]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this command :

```
pandas.merge(df,df2,how='inner')
```

you can know more about `pandas.merge` here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html.

This is quite like the SQL `JOIN` keyword.

[image: representation of sql join keyword]

Comment: Merge function creates a new column between the common rows of two df. I need to delete (in df1) the different rows between two df.

Comment: Are you sure. I'm pretty confident with my answer because I tested it can you show me why you think its a wrong answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to merge two data frames on columns with a different column name. In that case this is what you need:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create Example data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'F_Code': [1,2, 8], 'a': [3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Codice': [1,2,3], 'b': [1,2,5]})

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on='F_Code', 
              right_on='Codice').drop(columns=df2.columns)
```

result:

```
    F_Code  a
0   1       3
1   2       4
```

Comment: Ok, this function keep the common rows between two df but it duplicate them. I need to delete in df1 the rows that are not equals.

Comment: Did you mean that the columns of df2 are also added? I updated the answer, now it only returns the columns from df1.

Comment: Your solution is logically right but in my case it duplicates the number of the rows. I solved it with this code: df_new = [(df1['F_Code'].isin(df2['Codice']))] (i eliminate ~). Thanks for the support.